# Spring RestTemplate for iOS (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, spring, rest

I know that for consuming RestFul web services Spring provides special library [RestTemplate](https://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) for Android. What about similar library for Swift 4 (iOS)?
For android it was the only library that allowed to use cookies for state-full requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Foundation) seems to be the best choice here